# Kotlin is too loose in accessing Map entries

Tags: kotlin

Something that really frustrates me in Kotlin right now and I don't know how to fix this:

```kotlin
    val map = mapOf(1 to "one")
    val value = map[1] // value is String? instead of String
    val certainlyNot = map[999] // value is String? instead of compiler error
```

In my opinion, the compiler should be able to infer value type String for the `1` key and should prevent compilation when trying to access the `999` key.

**What data structure is better suited for my needs?**

Edit: Context -> I need to access the values in a loop like this

```kotlin
    for (key in map.keys) {
        val myValue = map[key] // myValue is String?
                               // but I don't understand why I am forced to do null checks
                               // when the key in question is certainly in the map AND maps to a String
    }
```

Comment: I don't see why you wouldn't just explicitly declare the types ? Type inference is only a compiler's best-effort to save your time beside the syntactic sugar. Does `val map = mapOf<Int, String>(1 to "one")` not work ? Also, maps are NOT supposed to be bound to a size. If that's the case, we're talking about an array of arrays (fixed sizes)

Answer (score 5):

The compiler doesn't know what's in the Map or somehow track everything that could possibly be in a Map at any point in your code. That would be too sophisticated for modern computers, which must continually compile your code as you type. I guess it might be theoretically possible, but if the compiler were this sophisticated, you wouldn't be able to get the real-time compilation that shows you compiler errors and warnings as you are working on your code. You'd have to stop and compile and wait quite some time each time you wanted to check it.

If you want to retrieve a value from a map that you *know* is there, then use `getValue()` instead of `[]`. This asserts to the compiler that you know the key is in the map and so it will not fail to retrieve it. If your assertion is incorrect, it will throw an exception at runtime.

```
for (key in map.keys) {
    val myValue = map.getValue(key) // myValue is nonnullable String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [destructuring declarations](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/destructuring-declarations.html#example-destructuring-declarations-and-maps) in for-loop and lambdas with map

```
for ((key, value) in map) {
    //...
}
```

```
map.forEach { (key, value) ->
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While `mapOf` is convenient for creating maps quickly, its type inference can sometimes be less precise, mainly when mixing key types or having non-existing keys.

When you have different key types in `mapOf` (like `1` and `"one"`), Kotlin infers the most general common type, which is `Any?`. This means both `map[1]` and `map["one"]` return `Any?`, which could be `String?`, `Int?`, or anything else.

`map[key]` returns `null` if the key doesn't exist. So, `map[999]` is `String?` because it might be `null`. Kotlin doesn't eagerly prevent compilation here, it assumes you might handle potential null values later.

**Better-Suited Data Structures**

`HashMap<Int, String> (or mutableMapOf<Int, String>)`

Explicitly declare key and value types: This ensures that `map[key]` always returns `String` without nullability. For non-existing keys you'll get a `null` at runtime, which you'll need to handle.

```
    val map = HashMap<Int, String>()

    map[1] = "one"

    val value = map[1] // value is String (not String?)

    val certainlyNot = map[999] // value is null
```

`Map<Int, String>.withDefault { null }`

Provide a default value for non-existing keys. This avoids `null` and might be cleaner if you expect missing keys often. Still returns `String?`, The type remains nullable because the default value could technically be `null`.

```
    val map = mapOf(1 to "one").withDefault { null }
    val value = map[1] // value is String? (but will be "one")
    val certainlyNot = map[999] // value is String? (but will be null)
```

Looping Without Null Checks, if you're certain that all keys in the loop exist and map to String, you have a few options:

1. Non-null assertion (`!!`), risky if you're wrong, throws an exception if the value is `null`.

```
    for (key in map.keys) {
        val myValue = map[key]!! // myValue is String
    }
```

2. Safe cast (`as?`) with handling potential null values:

```
    for (key in map.keys) {
        val myValue = map[key] as? String
        if (myValue != null) {
            // use myValue (which is now String)
        } else {
            // handle the unexpected null case
        }
    }
```

3. Filter for existing keys

```
    for (key in map.keys.filter { map.containsKey(it) }) {
        val myValue = map[key]!! // myValue is String (guaranteed)
    }
```

Comment: Your HashMap example is wrong. Both map[1] and map[999] will be `String?`

Answer (score 0):

Because Kotlin is statically typed, it is necessary to define all of an object's properties at compile time if you want safe access to them (and errors for attempting to access properties that are not present).

However, if you are willing to define those properties, you can use Kotlin's [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html) feature to have *both* property access and iteration over those properties (at the cost of a bit of boilerplate code).

To do this, you can define a base class like this<sup>1</sup>:

```
abstract class SuperMap : Iterable<String> {

    private val underlyingMap: LinkedHashMap<String, String> = linkedMapOf()

    override fun iterator(): Iterator<String> {
        return underlyingMap.values.iterator()
    }
    
    protected class SuperMapProperty(private val initValue: String) {
        operator fun provideDelegate(thisRef: SuperMap, property: KProperty<*>): SuperMapPropertyDelegate {
            return SuperMapPropertyDelegate()
                .apply { setValue(thisRef, property, initValue) }
        }
    }

    protected class SuperMapPropertyDelegate {
        operator fun getValue(thisRef: SuperMap, property: KProperty<*>): String {
            /**
             * Delegation approach makes this a safe call
             */
            return thisRef.underlyingMap.getValue(property.name)
        }

        operator fun setValue(thisRef: SuperMap, property: KProperty<*>, value: String) {
            thisRef.underlyingMap[property.name] = value
        }
    }

}
```

Here we have used delegates to give a type-safe way of defining and retrieving properties whilst storing those properties in an underlying map. This underlying map allows us to implement the `Iterable` interface, giving us the ability to iterate over those properties as well. You could go further and implement `List`, `Map` or another similar interface depending on the precise functionality you want<sup>2</sup>.

Then you are free to define a new class with all the features you desired, ensuring that you use the delegate to define each property:

```
class MyMap : SuperMap() {
    val _1 by SuperMapProperty("Kotlin")
    var _2 by SuperMapProperty("?")
}

fun main(){
    val myMap = MyMap()
    println(myMap._1) // Normal property getting
    myMap._2 = "FTW" // and setting
    for (each in myMap) // plus iteration
        println("Iterating $each")
}
```

See [playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS45LjIyIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbi5yZWZsZWN0LktQcm9wZXJ0eVxuXG5jbGFzcyBNeU1hcCA6IFN1cGVyTWFwKCkge1xuICAgIHZhbCBfMSBieSBTdXBlck1hcFByb3BlcnR5KFwiS290bGluXCIpXG4gICAgdmFyIF8yIGJ5IFN1cGVyTWFwUHJvcGVydHkoXCI/XCIpXG59XG5cbmZ1biBtYWluKCl7XG4gICAgdmFsIG15TWFwID0gTXlNYXAoKVxuICAgIHByaW50bG4obXlNYXAuXzEpIC8vIE5vcm1hbCBwcm9wZXJ0eSBnZXR0aW5nXG4gICAgbXlNYXAuXzIgPSBcIkZUV1wiIC8vIGFuZCBzZXR0aW5nXG4gICAgZm9yIChlYWNoIGluIG15TWFwKSAvLyBwbHVzIGl0ZXJhdGlvblxuICAgICAgICBwcmludGxuKFwiSXRlcmF0aW5nICRlYWNoXCIpXG59XG5cbmFic3RyYWN0IGNsYXNzIFN1cGVyTWFwIDogSXRlcmFibGU8U3RyaW5nPiB7XG5cbiAgICBwcml2YXRlIHZhbCB1bmRlcmx5aW5nTWFwOiBMaW5rZWRIYXNoTWFwPFN0cmluZywgU3RyaW5nPiA9IGxpbmtlZE1hcE9mKClcblxuICAgIG92ZXJyaWRlIGZ1biBpdGVyYXRvcigpOiBJdGVyYXRvcjxTdHJpbmc+IHtcbiAgICAgICAgcmV0dXJuIHVuZGVybHlpbmdNYXAudmFsdWVzLml0ZXJhdG9yKClcbiAgICB9XG4gICAgXG4gICAgcHJvdGVjdGVkIGNsYXNzIFN1cGVyTWFwUHJvcGVydHkocHJpdmF0ZSB2YWwgaW5pdFZhbHVlOiBTdHJpbmcpIHtcbiAgICAgICAgb3BlcmF0b3IgZnVuIHByb3ZpZGVEZWxlZ2F0ZSh0aGlzUmVmOiBTdXBlck1hcCwgcHJvcGVydHk6IEtQcm9wZXJ0eTwqPik6IFN1cGVyTWFwUHJvcGVydHlEZWxlZ2F0ZSB7XG4gICAgICAgICAgICByZXR1cm4gU3VwZXJNYXBQcm9wZXJ0eURlbGVnYXRlKClcbiAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAuYXBwbHkgeyBzZXRWYWx1ZSh0aGlzUmVmLCBwcm9wZXJ0eSwgaW5pdFZhbHVlKSB9XG4gICAgICAgIH1cbiAgICB9XG5cbiAgICBwcm90ZWN0ZWQgY2xhc3MgU3VwZXJNYXBQcm9wZXJ0eURlbGVnYXRlIHtcbiAgICAgICAgb3BlcmF0b3IgZnVuIGdldFZhbHVlKHRoaXNSZWY6IFN1cGVyTWFwLCBwcm9wZXJ0eTogS1Byb3BlcnR5PCo+KTogU3RyaW5nIHtcbiAgICAgICAgICAgIC8qKlxuICAgICAgICAgICAgICogRGVsZWdhdGlvbiBhcHByb2FjaCBtYWtlcyB0aGlzIGEgc2FmZSBjYWxsXG4gICAgICAgICAgICAgKi9cbiAgICAgICAgICAgIHJldHVybiB0aGlzUmVmLnVuZGVybHlpbmdNYXAuZ2V0VmFsdWUocHJvcGVydHkubmFtZSlcbiAgICAgICAgfVxuXG4gICAgICAgIG9wZXJhdG9yIGZ1biBzZXRWYWx1ZSh0aGlzUmVmOiBTdXBlck1hcCwgcHJvcGVydHk6IEtQcm9wZXJ0eTwqPiwgdmFsdWU6IFN0cmluZykge1xuICAgICAgICAgICAgdGhpc1JlZi51bmRlcmx5aW5nTWFwW3Byb3BlcnR5Lm5hbWVdID0gdmFsdWVcbiAgICAgICAgfVxuICAgIH1cblxufSJ9) for this in one place.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that two delegates, a provider and a property delegate, have been used. This is another pattern to facilitate providing an initial value to the property without additional memory usage (as would be the case by storing that initial value in the property delegate as well as the underlying map). See [Kotlin discussions](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/memory-leak-when-setting-initial-value-with-property-delegate/24908) for more on that

<sup>2</sup>If a more complex interface than `Iterable` is being implemented, you might want to take advantage of the [delegation feature](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegation.html) so that you don't have to make the link between the underlying map and the implemented methods by hand as I have done above (easy as it was one method). This could be done at the cost of having the `LinkedHashMap` as a default value provided in the constructor of base class (although this is not ideal as it allows the user to override that default). This would look like:

```
abstract class SuperMap(
    private val underlyingMap: LinkedHashMap<String, String> = linkedMapOf()
) : Map by underlyingMap
```